# RichTextBox with diagonal text lines

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, rotatetransform

I want to have a customized RichTextBox control to use in an application like MS Word. But the challenge is to input text diagonally. Currently I used a RichTextBox and a TextEffect for Runs in Document property of the RichTextBox to show text diagonally and it works. Unfortunately the caret appears in its original position and direction so the user will be confused what he edits, where he types and what he selects. Can you help me?

```
  <Style TargetType="Run">
    <Setter Property="TextEffects">
      <Setter.Value>
        <TextEffectCollection>
          <TextEffect PositionCount="99999">
            <TextEffect.Transform>
              <TransformGroup>
              <ScaleTransform/>
              <SkewTransform/>
              <RotateTransform Angle="30"/>
              <TranslateTransform X="30" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
          </TextEffect.Transform>
         </TextEffect>
       </TextEffectCollection>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Gray">
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" >
                                <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"></RotateTransform>
                                </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox Height="300" Width="300">
        <RichTextBox.Document>
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run>
                    </Run>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox.Document>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

**Update**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Name="Border" Padding="1" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="Gray">
                            <ScrollViewer  x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                                <ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="20"/>
                                </ScrollViewer.LayoutTransform>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                            <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can use rotate transform also..try with rotate transformation also

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in this case, text lines are not aligned to a vertical line and after a few lines the text overflows the richtextbox (lines will start from outside)

Comment: Thank you. In this new approach the letters lean and I don't want skewed text.

Comment: +1 This answer is working great with rotate transform and skewe transform also.

Comment: I added a new SkewTransform by -20 in a TextEffect to negate the skew effect on the text and it have an interesting look now.
But I'm not sure this could be the best practice.

Comment: have you tried my skewtransform code with rotate transform ?? rotate transfom will not show skewed text.